# Floatingfigure is not being shown

Tags: floats, warnings

I have an issue with a floatfigure which I haven't got any clue how to overcome. I am not shown any errors or warnings except that reference `abb:phase_neutralstabil` is not defined, which is weird because it is indeed defined, though after the reference (which should not be a problem).

Here is my minimal example that does not work as it should:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Diese Pakete sind
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % für die Verwendung 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % von Umlauten im tex-file
\usepackage{lmodern}        % Schriftart, die am Bildschirm besser lesbar ist
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}        %Einbinden von Grafiken & Tabellen in den Fließtext
\usepackage{graphicx}       % Zum Einbinden von Formeln
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}            % Zur Darstellung von Webadressen
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatflt}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma,per=frac,fraction=nice,locale=DE,separate-uncertainty=true]{siunitx}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc}
\let\i\undefined
\DeclareMathOperator{\i}{i}
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\let\d\undefined
\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Damit ergibt sich eine weitere wichtige Eigenschaft, die den selbsterregten Oszillator zur Synchronisation befähigt. Seine Phase lässt sich beliebig entlang des Grenzzyklus verschieben und diese Verschiebung bleibt erhalten (s. Abb.~\ref{abb:phase_neutralstabil}). Die Phase des selbsterregten Oszillators ist \textbf{neutral stabil}:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\d\phi}{\d t}=\omega_0 \text{.}
\end{equation}

\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{1em}
    \includegraphics[scale=1.0]{phase_diagram_self-sustained_shifted.pdf}
    \caption{Die Phase des selbsterregten Oszillators ist neutral stabil und kann entlang des Grenzzyklus verschoben werden, ohne dabei dessen Form zu verändern. (\cite{ltv:pikovsky}, S.~)}
    \label{abb:phase_neutralstabil}
\end{floatingfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: beware that  `\DeclareMathOperator{\i}{i}` will break all accented `i` input as utf-8 characters

Answer (score 2):

The `floatingfigure` environment in the example is only `1em` wide (this is approximately the size of a lower case 'm'), which presumably is too small for the contents. Increasing the width shows the image.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
    \caption{Die Phase des selbsterregten Oszillators ist neutral stabil und kann entlang des Grenzzyklus verschoben werden, ohne dabei dessen Form zu verandern.}
    \label{abb:phase_neutralstabil}
\end{floatingfigure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that there are other packages that are more commonly used for inline images, such as `wrapfig`.